# How can i receive data from external url using json?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Recently i am learning json to create apps.I have a  doubt in a Json , php  based chat system .
In this , the code work fine for same origin policy.But for sending and receiving data from external url, it successfully sends data to external php.But not receiving any data from server.I search in internet to solve this problem , and found jsonp as alternative.  I tried jsonp , but i m not sure if am correct because i am new to ajax itself.

Please don't mis understand my question.I want to load a index.html file from localhost , when i send request to external url (anysite.com/xx/ajax.php) .It process and returns the data back to index.html.But the problem is my data is sended finely and processed on the server but it doesn't return to remote file.But it works fine for same server.

```
$.tzPOST = function(action,data,callback)
{
    $.post('http://anysite.com/xx/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
    $.get('http://anysite.com/xx/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}
```

please help me with a code.

Comment: Do not see any attempt to use `jsonp`.

Comment: I tried , but it's not working.So again i changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant receive JSON from external web by JavaScript, because of the policy.

But you can do AJAX request on your PHP file and there you can get the JSON by file_get_content https://www.php.net/file_get_contents function.

Answer (score 0):

For using(working) with  `jsonp`, u can take ready solution [jquery-jsonp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp)
 from `GitHub`.

Example of using (by you question):

```
$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
  var url = 'http://anysite.com/xx/ajax.php?action='+action;

  $.jsonp({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   callbackParameter: callback,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   data: data,
   timeout: 10000,
   success: function(json){
     alert('success')
   },
   error: function(){
      alert('error')
   }
});
```